# How to unlock all tracks in Linux version of SuperTuxKart 0.9?

Tags: games

I want to set up an open-source gaming party, kinda small, in my local area, all of the machines running Ubuntu. One of the games I plan on have there is *SuperTuxKart*, specifically the 0.9 version. I want to unlock everything in the game without taking the time to play through the entire campaign mode, so I figured that I would cheat. I've seen millions of guides telling you to modify ~/.config/supertuxkart/challenges.xml, but for the life of me I cannot find that file in that location. Please help, I need this up and running in a week or so.

Comment: You probably need to launch the game at least once for the config file to get created. I presume you did ?

Comment: @JonasCz Yes, I did, and I even beat a race in the campaign mode.

Comment: Dont want to be he bad boy who breaks this to you but this isnt about Ubuntu.

Comment: @videonauth If I posted this on gaming.stackexchange, the most plausible alternative to AskUbuntu for this question, most of the people there would either be confused about the "Linux-speak" in this question, or they would simply have no idea what the heck SuperTuxKart is.

Comment: Well there aswell qwould be the distribution overriding [Linux & Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com) Stackexchange site :)

Comment: @videonauth Actually, the computers I plan on using for the event run Ubuntu, and I changed "Linux" to "Ubuntu" in my question to clarify.

Comment: Did my answer help you ?

Answer (score 12):

Yay, I finally figured this out!

Find your [configuration directory](http://supertuxkart.net/FAQ) -- mine was in `~/.config/supertuxkart/0.8.2/`.

Open `players.xml` and find where the challenges are listed under the `<story-mode>` tag.

Change all occurrences of `solved="none"` to `solved="easy"`. (You can also say `solved="hard"`; I'm not sure what the difference is.)

Sources:

- http://forum.freegamedev.net/viewtopic.php?t=6289&p=63809
- https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/33dosv/supertuxkart_09_released_full_review/.

Comment: Just a note for those having trouble opening it, file file uses a UTF-32 encoding.  Gedit will open it, though you will have to open it, select UTF-32, close Gedit, and open it again; otherwise the file may not save (Gedit bug?)

Comment: Krusader and Kwrite are OK with UTF-32.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [STK FAQ](http://supertuxkart.sourceforge.net/FAQ#Where_does_STK_store_the_user_config_file.3F), there are two possible locations for the config file:

- `~/.config/supertuxkart/0.8.2`
- `~/.supertuxkart/0.8.2`

In one of these directories, you should find a `.xml` file (probably `challenges.xml`), in which you'll need to change all occurrences of "false" to "true", for each track. Note that 0.9 stores its config data in the `0.8.2` directory, since the files are compatible with various versions.

Have fun :-)